# Bluetooth Smart: is it sensible to choose a device based on its peripheral name

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I have an application (Basically an Arduino) that I connect to from iOS (and might use Android in the future as well) using BLE. I reprogram the BLE hosts to a specific value so that the when I ask the peripherals name after it gets discovered in iOS can be accepted or rejected.

I'm however not sure that this is a good way to do. The name has a code that users can easily change to an other (always valid) code. That way if two modules are up and running at the same time, users will be sure that only the module they are linked to is the one they want to be linked to. This is a bit the same like connecting a mouse / keyboard of course using 'normal' bluetooth.

Comment: So the user chooses the name to link to?

Comment: Well I actually print a QR code on the back of the Arduino so the user can easily decide what module to use. That works quite well already. The user cannot modify the peripherals name since it is 'hard' coded into the Bluetooth module.

Comment: So I'm not clear on the question then. If you show all of the names of the available devices to the user and have them choose one then that seems fine.

Comment: The thing is, it is a bit like 'hacking' isn't it? But I don't want to keep connecting and disconnecting all the devices, otherwise I think the BD_ADDR would be more elegant to use and not a code in the devices (peripheral) name. But I'm not sure if it is possible to read the BD_ADDR from the Bluetooth device without connecting to it in the first place.

Comment: Does the name have another purpose than to be shown to the user (then that other purpose could probably be considered as a hack...).

Comment: We use it (the same code) as a serial number too (obviously). The app decided when it sees a new bluetooth smart module based on the code if it wants to connect to the device or not.